# How do I get the OpenSSH SFTP subsystem for the client to honor LogLevel settings?

Tags: ssh, sftp, loglevel

When connecting to a server via SFTP, I can use `-o` to specify a `LogLevel`, like so:

```
sftp -oLogLevel=DEBUG3 username@host
```

This spits out a ton of debug information about the login process.  However, it gets to this point and all debugs cease:

```
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug2: channel 0: request subsystem confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 131072
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: subsystem request accepted on channel 0
Connected to host.
sftp> ls
Some    Directories
sftp> cd Some
sftp> ls
sftp> quit
debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 4 len 0
debug2: channel 0: read failed
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 0: send eof
debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Received disconnect from <IP>: 11: User Disconnected
```

What about that `ls` command?  Where can I get debugs for that?  `cd`?  `quit`?

Also, I don't have any control over the remote server, so I'm not asking about configuring the SFTP subsystem on the server via `sshd_config`.  I've tried that and it doesn't work.

The `sftp-client.c` file has calls to debug3, so where are they going?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-vvv` switch to the `sftp`. The options `-o` are passed directly to the `ssh` process but not effective to the `sftp` itself.

It is well described in the manual page for `sftp`:

> ```
> -v      Raise logging level.  This option is also passed to ssh.
> ```

Also the `-o` explains that it is passed to the `ssh` and not effective in `sftp` process:

> `-o ssh_option`
>
> Can be used to pass options to ssh in the format used in ssh_config(5).  This is useful for specifying options for which there is no separate sftp command-line flag.  For example, to specify an alternate port use: sftp -oPort=24.  For full details of the options listed below, and their possible values, see ssh_config(5).

Comment: Yep, that works.

The documentation on that option is rather poor.  "This option is also passed to ssh" says nothing about the SFTP subsystem.  In fact, I didn't believe you at first when I saw it.  Also, I don't see in the docs where it says that `-o` is not effective in the sftp process.

Comment: It is not a problem of a subsystem. The crucial is understanding that running `sftp` is running two processes. The `sftp` client which has its options and `ssh` which has different options. You were getting the logs from the `ssh` process, but not from `sftp` client. With the subsystem, you might be confused by the server side (there it is really a subsystem), but on the client, `sftp` is running "over" `ssh` so from this point of view it is not a subsystem, but `ssh` is a subprocess of `sftp`.